# IsConcurrencyToken in the fluent API is not affecting the migration scaffolding

Tags: c#, entity-framework

This looks really simple and dumb, but it's not working for some reason... I got this line in my `DbContext`'s `OnModelCreating` method :

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Client>().Property(o => o.RowVersion).IsConcurrencyToken();
```

And I got this line in the Client entity :

```
public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
```

And the scaffolded migration ends up like this :

```
AddColumn("dbo.Client", "RowVersion", c => c.Binary());
```

If I add the attribute `[Timestamp]` to the property, then it works and gives me :

```
AlterColumn("dbo.Client", "RowVersion", c => c.Binary(nullable: false, fixedLength: true, timestamp: true, storeType: "rowversion"));
```

Is there something I'm missing here? I'm really confused... Theres nothing more to do in the [tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/handling-concurrency-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application).

-Edit-

Adding `.IsRowVersion()` with the fluent API made it work. Is the tutorial from Microsoft simply wrong or is that a breaking change without EF6 versions? (I'm on 6.1.1 I believe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding .IsRowVersion() with the fluent API made it work.

Is the tutorial from Microsoft simply wrong or is that a breaking change without EF6 versions? (I'm on 6.1.1 I believe) If someone can answer this, I will gladly change the accepted answer to you more detailed answer.

Answer (score 2):

**IsConcurrencyToken** does not work for byte[]

the data type is nvarchar(max)
its value is always null if you don't initialize it
its value is not auto-incremented when a record is updated.

**IsRowVersion** on the other hand, has datatype rowversion, 
so
its value is never null, and
its value is always auto-incremented when a record is updated.
and it automatically configures the property to be an optimistic concurrency token.